# How to find MySQL error log file on Windows?

Tags: mysql

I just downloaded MySQL on Windows, and I am trying to run MySQl from the command line. When I try to login as root, the server simply freezes and does nothing. If I enter the incorrect password, it denies me access, but when I enter the correct password, it's hanging.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwau4.png)

I am trying to figure out where to view the MySQL log/error files, but cannot find them on my system.

Answer (score 1):

They can be found in the **hidden folder**:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data
```

But you should run the MySQL installer and reconfigure the server and follow the steps, where you enter the password.

Comment: I am able to connect to the root inside MySQL Workbench though with the same password. Is it necessary to reconfigure to be able to connect through command line?

Comment: you must reconfigure it and enable the legacy mode

Answer (score 0):

From the [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-troubleshooting.html#:%7E:text=The%20error%20log%20is%20located,directory%20is%20hidden%20by%20default.)

> The error log is located in the data directory specified in your
> my.ini file. The default data directory location is C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data, or C:\ProgramData\Mysql on Windows
> 7 and Windows Server 2008. The C:\ProgramData directory is hidden by
> default.